# Generating a png-File on the desktop from a screenshot made to the pasteboard on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, image, screenshot, pasteboard

Hi stackoverflow forum,

I've written a macOS swiftUI app, which checks the availability to a website, i.e. to my cloud.
In the case, the access is lost, I'm creating a screenshot to the pasteboard and I'm generating a POST request to a PHP script on my webserver, to send an information email to my email address.

I'm using the following 2 functions, to generate the screenshot and save it to the pasteboard. All based on the tutorial (very good!) from Grace Huang (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nnYsRrtweA)

```
//MARK: - Ein Screenshot wird erstellt und im Pasteboard abgespeichert

func erfolgreichEinScreenshotErstellt() -> Bool{
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/sbin/screencapture"
    task.arguments = ["-c"]
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    let status = task.terminationStatus
    return status == 0
}

//MARK: - Das gecaptured Bild wird aus dem Pastboard geholt und in das image geladen

func dasBildAbholenUndZeigen() -> NSImage {
    let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
    guard pasteboard.canReadItem(withDataConformingToTypes:
        NSImage.imageTypes) else{
        return NSImage()
    }
    guard let image = NSImage(pasteboard: pasteboard) else {
        return NSImage()
    }
    let tiffData = image.tiffRepresentation!
    let pngData = NSBitmapImageRep(data: tiffData)?.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])

    return image
}
```

Everything works fine till here!

The last step I like to do, I need a little help for: how can I save the "image" as a .png-file with a given name to my desktop for further use, i.e. generating a pdf file or so from the png file.

As you can see, I've tried the following code but than I've got stuck:

.........

```
    let tiffData = image.tiffRepresentation!
    let pngData = NSBitmapImageRep(data: tiffData)?.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])
```

Thanks in advance, if someone likes to help me with some code or a hint to a solution idea.

Best

Thomas

Comment: Can you clarify you got stuck? an error or unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is missing the actual saving to disk call:

```
let tiffData = image.tiffRepresentation!
let pngData = NSBitmapImageRep(data: tiffData)?.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])
let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/*YourUsername*/Desktop/testImage.png")
try? pngData?.write(to: path) // << save to disk
```

Comment: Hi, the code works. The  question is fully answered. Good support, Thomas

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned the line to write the code to disk is missing.

However your approach is cumbersome. `screencapture` can save the image directly to disk just be replacing `-c` with the file path. The pasteboard detour is not needed.

But there is a general issue: Most likely your app is sandboxed. If so using `Process()` is not allowed.
Fortunately you can take a screenshot with the Core Graphics API.

This function captures the contents of the main screen and saves the image in the **Downloads** folder (you have to enable it in the sandbox settings) with an iso8601 timestamp and returns the URL

```
enum ScreenshotError: Error {
    case cannotCreateImage
}

func takeScreenshot()  throws -> URL {
    let mainDisplayID = CGMainDisplayID()
    
    let timeStamp = Date().formatted(.iso8601.dateSeparator(.omitted).timeSeparator(.omitted))
    let fileUrl = URL.downloadsDirectory.appending(path: "screenshot_" + timeStamp + ".png")
    let screenshot = CGDisplayCreateImage(mainDisplayID)!
    let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: screenshot)
    guard let jpegData = bitmapRep.representation(using: .png, properties: [:]) else {
        throw ScreenshotError.cannotCreateImage
    }
    try jpegData.write(to: fileUrl)
    return fileUrl
}
```

And call it

```
do {
    let fileURL = try takeScreenshot()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```